# Determinant of the Sum in an Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant

Given that: $detA > 0$ and $detB > 0$, is it the case that $det(A+B) \ge 0$?

Comment: why do you think that is a possibility?? the most basic example is... $A=I$ $B=-I$..

Comment: Good point, but would det(A+B) >= 0?  (Would it be positive?)

Comment: i am not sure who upvoted my comment but, I did not mention the size of the matrix $I$ which is necessary for $\det B >0$... :D but i hope the user got the idea

Comment: that is up to you to check for positiveness....

Comment: Use a basic two by two example (i.e. the identity and the negative identity as suggested.) Then add them. See what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\ 1&2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\ 0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\det\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}=-1$.